# Is there a fast way to add album cover art to 199 different albums

Tags: music

I want to add cover art to my songs, but I have 763 songs, 110 artists, and 199 albums. Right now I can add cover art using EasyTAG, but this could take weeks. Is there any way to do this faster. There are tons of apps for Ubuntu, wouldn't there be one that gets the cover art and embed it in the mp3 for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try Album Cover Art Downloader.

Album Cover Art Downloader will semi-automatically download album cover images for your music collection. All you have to do is point it at the root of your music directory and for each directory, the program will download a set of corresponding (well, best guess) album covers from the Internet, from which you can choose one that suits your fancy.<sup>[Album Cover Art Downloader](http://www.unrealvoodoo.org/hiteck/projects/albumart/)</sup>

Also you can take a look at [Bliss](http://www.blisshq.com/download.html)

Answer (score -2):

Keep the music files of the album in a folder, including the image of the album (jpg, pnm...).

Then *right-click* on the folder and select properties. Click on the folder icon and select the image for the folder.

Comment: -1, have you tried this solution?